# sqlalchemy orm bulk insert from pandas data frame when np.nan

Tags: dataframe, orm, sqlalchemy, null, bulkinsert

I am using sqlalchemy ORM facility to bulk insert a Pandas DataFrame into a Microsoft SQL Server DB:

```
my_engine = create_engine(url.URL(**my_db_url))
Session = sessionmaker(bind=my_engine )
my_session = Session()
start = time.time()
my_session.bulk_insert_mappings(TableObject, mysample)
my_session.commit()
durata = time.time() -start
my_session.close()
```

Here `mysample` is a list of dict created as:

```
mysample=myDataFrame.to_dict(orient='records')
```

that fits with TableObject, that is declared as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, BigInteger, String, Integer, Sequence, DateTime,Date, Float, ForeignKey, Boolean, VARCHAR, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.schema import PrimaryKeyConstraint
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql import null

Base = declarative_base()
class TableObject(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "dbo"}

    Key1= Column('Key1',String(1), nullable=False)
    Key2= Column('Key2',Integer, nullable=False)
    Key3= Column('Key3',Integer, nullable=False)
    Key4= Column('Key4',BigInteger, nullable=False)
    SCORE_DATE= Column('SCORE_DATE',DateTime)
    ScoreVal= Column("ScoreVal",Float)

    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint(
        Key1, Key2,Key3,Key4
        ), {}
    )
```

ScoreVal may seldom be np.nan. What is the best approach to bulk insert the DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found somewhere on SO, before using bulk insert it could be necessary to replace `np.nan` with `None`:

```
mysample= mysample.replace({np.nan: None})
```

This works with MSSSQL SERVER and ORACLE.